# Django, custom error pages redirects to 500 instead of 404

Tags: python, django

I have production server which has these settings:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'my.ip.address', 'example.com']
```

Then in my main `urls.py` file I have added this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include, handler404, handler500

handler500 = 'main.views.error_500'
handler404 = 'main.views.error_404'
```

My `main.views` has these:

```
def error_404(request):
    return render(request, 'main/errors/404.html', status=404)


def error_500(request):
    return render(request, 'main/errors/500.html', status=500)
```

When I deploy my production server and try to open page that does not exists, it should redirect to my `error_404` view. However, it redirects to my `error_500` view. Why this is happening?

Comment: Did you tried checking the same in debugging mode ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the templates are in the correct spot? Are there any errors occurring during the rendering of those templates?

Comment: @Umair Debugging mode does not show my custom views, but it shows that error is 404, which is correct.

Comment: @Shadow templates are in corrrect spot.

Comment: @Mr.D Can you render those templates normally? (ie, set up a url that points to the error_404 view)

Comment: Is it only showing the wrong template or is the status code wrong too? Check response headers using your browser's inspector.

Comment: Add a logging management that sends you an email in case of error in production. Without debug is impossible to understand why the 500 is raised.

Comment: @Shadow templates loads normally if I add them to urls

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question is three months old but for the community this is how I solved this:

The 404-page-not-found-view needs an "exception" argument:

```
def error_404(request, exception):
    return render(request,'myapp/404.html', status = 404)
```

> The default 404 view will pass two variables to the template:
>   request_path, which is the URL that resulted in the error, and
>   exception, which is a useful representation of the exception that
>   triggered the view (e.g. containing any message passed to a specific
>   Http404 instance).

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view

I'm Django-noob but I *suppose* that without this argument the 404 trigger a 500.

One more thing: It works for me without the import : "from django.conf.urls import handler404, handler500"

Comment: Thanks for this. There are a lot of tutorials out there that leave the exception parameter out.