# django 500 error coming instead of 404 for custom error page

Tags: django

here is my views.py

```
def handler_404(request):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)

def handler_500(request):
    return render(request, '500.html', status=404)
```

here is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from finish.views import handler_404,handler_500
from django.conf.urls import (
                handler400,
                handler403,
                handler404,
                handler500
            )


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include("scrap.urls")),
    path('', include("details.urls")),
    path('', include("finalize.urls")),
    path('', include("finish.urls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

handler404 = handler_404
handler500 = handler_500
```

when i am typing some url in which is not exist 
it is coming "Server Error(500)" instead of coming "page not found(404)" error.

Please have a look into this....

Comment: Chances are the problem lies within of your paths which were assigned to `urlpatterns`. You probably have some pattern which catches unknown url and passes it to some view that produces an error. You should check carefully all your applications' urls. Also it's generally not a great practice to handle path `''` by multiple applications

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but ill rederect you to Nico's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399456/django-custom-error-pages-redirects-to-500-instead-of-404/54165066#54165066?newreg=e70f1cd416b0426897cfcfde05b3d708). I spent too mutch time finding that.

Im running django 3.0.2 and to sum up i did this:
**prodject - urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include, handler404
import app.views

urlpatterns = [
.
.
.
]
handler404 = app.views.error_404
```

**app - views.py**

```
.
.
.
def error_404(request, exception):
    return render(request,'app/404.html', status = 404)
```

After reading many tutorials, I found out that most of them ommits the exception

Then put a 404.html in your app/templates/app folder

Hope someone finds this usefull..